# Auto close fa fa-ellipsis-v when clicking the page

Tags: angular

[image: Actions Panel]I am new to an angular supporting existing project. There are actions in fa fa-ellipsis-v which you click and it opens up and you make the selection(See attached image). The problem now is it always remains static it doesn't auto close unless you go and click it to close or even if I click anywhere on the page.

How I auto close fa fa-ellipsis-v or make it disappear when clicking the browser

**HTML**

```
<td>
<div style="padding: 0px 15px;" (click)="toggle(rowIndex); isActionsOpen = !isActionsOpen">
    <a>
        <span id="actionOpenIcon{{rowIndex}}" class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </a>
<div id="cusaction{{rowIndex}}" hidden="hidden" class="cus_tbl_actions" [@fadeInAnimation]>
    <div *ngIf="rowData.status !== 'Inactive'" class="row cus_action_btn" (click)="actionSheetService.showActionSheet(customerAccountActionSheet); selectCustomer(rowData, 'view accounts')">
        <div class="col-3" style="text-align: right;">
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9" style="text-align: start;">View Accounts</div>
    </div>
    <hr *ngIf="rowData.status !== 'Inactive'" />
    <div *ngIf="rowData.status !== 'Inactive'" class="row cus_action_btn" [pRowToggler]="rowData" (click)="selectCustomer(rowData, 'edit')">
        <div class="col-3" style="text-align: right;">
            <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9" style="text-align: start;">Edit</div>
    </div>
    <hr *ngIf="rowData.status !== 'Inactive'" />
    <div *ngIf="rowData.status !== 'Inactive'" class="row cus_action_btn" (click)="notificationService.showNotification(cancelCustomerModal); selectCustomer(rowData, 'view accounts')">
        <div class="col-3" style="text-align: right;">
            <span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9" style="text-align: start;">Cancel</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could write this code yourself, or use Angular material menu and save yourself a bunch of time.https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples. It does what you want I suspect.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this one. It looks easier.